# How to reduce phantomjs memory consumption?

Tags: webkit, automated-tests, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs with casperjs to run multiple tests and it looks like each instance of PhantomJS takes ~106M of RAM. Is it possible to reduce that amount? Is there a simple way to run tests in multiple "tabs"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** As pointed by @newfurniturey, *release* is now deprecated. We must use *close*:
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html

Don't know if that helps, but the *release* function could be a good tail :
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/release.html

> Releases memory heap associated with this page. Do not use the page
>   instance after calling this.
>
> Due to some technical limitation, the web page object might not be
>   completely garbage collected. This is often encountered when the same
>   object is used over and over again. **Calling this function may stop the increasing heap allocation.**

:)

Comment: `release()` has been deprecated in favor of the new [`close()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#wiki-webpage-close) function (introduced in PhantomJS 1.7)

Comment: How can I use close()? The documentation is not complete.